# Can't get the fill of a map's selection to stay after being clicked

Tags: d3.js

I have a click-to-zoom function enabled on my US state map that was adapted from [mbostock's example found here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590).

The zoom is working well enough, but I'd like the selected state to remain filled with the on('mouseover') fill permanently until clicked again or if another element is clicked.

I added to the clicked function so it would change the class of the selection to 'clicked.' I then made a conditional to check if the selection was clicked or on in the on('mouseout') function.

So why isn't the clicked function permanently changing the color to the desired fill and keep it that way until it is no longer clicked?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
function draw(geo_data) {

      var margin = 0,
        width = 2000 - margin,
        height = 525 - margin;

      var centered;

      var svg = d3.select('#map')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin)
        .attr('height', height + margin)
        .append('g');

      var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa();

      var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

  var map = svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(geo_data.features)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('fill', 'rgba(105, 105, 105, 1)')
    .attr('stroke', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)')
    .attr('stroke-width', 0.5)
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
      d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'rgba(108, 122, 137, 0.5)')
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      if (d3.select(this).classed('clicked')) {
        console.log('is clicked')
        d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'rgba(105, 105, 105, 1)')
      } else {
        console.log('is not clicked')
        d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'rgba(105, 105, 105, 1)')
      }
    })
    // Calls click-to-zoom function defined below.
    .on('click', clicked);

function clicked(d) {

    // Should change the selection to the darker fill.
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'rgba(108, 122, 137, 0.5)');

    // Should keep fill if clicked and remove if not clicked.

    if (d3.select(this).classed('clicked')) {
      d3.select(this).attr('clicked', false);
    } else {
      d3.select(this).attr('clicked', true);
    }

        var x, y, k;

        if (d && centered !== d) {
          var centroid = path.centroid(d);
          x = centroid[0];
          y = centroid[1];
          k = 1.9;
          centered = d;
        } else {
          x = width / 3;
          y = height / 3;
          k = 1;
          centered = null;
        }

        map.selectAll('path')
          .classed('active', centered && function(d) {
            return d === centered;
          });

        map.transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 3 + ',' + height / 3 + ')scale(' + k + ')translate(' + -x + ',' + -y + ')')
          .style('stroke-width', 1 / k + 'px');

        // Transitions circles upon zoom.

        svg.selectAll('circle')
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 3 + ',' + height / 3 + ')scale(' + k + ')translate(' + -x + ',' + -y + ')')
          .style('stroke-width', 1 / k + 'px');
      }
```

Comment: Could you share a fully reproducible example?

Comment: Here is the link to the entire code on Github: https://github.com/dieterholger/US-Gun-Manufacturing-Interactive/blob/master/index.html

Comment: You are setting the clicked class wrong within the click function:  `d3.select(this).attr('clicked', false/true);` , instead of `.classed("clicked",false/true)`

Comment: OK, so now it seems to not change color on mouseover when zoomed in but it won't go to the darker fill rgba(108, 122, 137, 0.5)

Comment: NVM! I got it in the css. Thanks!